# mul eax with declared .data value in NASM assembly

Tags: xcode, assembly, nasm

I'm a total beginner at Assembly and i have been trying to get the basics in NASM. Im on a mac, using xcode and i have started dealing with data and i have a simple question.

I have had a hard time finding the answer and the manual for NASM is very overwhelming.

This must be super basic for you NASM guru's out there.

if i declare a variable out in memory

```
section   .data
    counter dw 0

global    _start
_start:
    inc counter    ; i get a "invalid combination of opcode and operands" here
ret
```

Is it so that i must move the memory into a register to perform operations on it, and i can't manipulate memory "in place"?

Im sorry if this is a silly question, but i have tried googling this and couldn't find a clear straight up answer.

Comment: See the nasm manual, in particular the [Section 2.2.2: NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2). You will also need to specify operation size since it can't be deduced. TL;DR: use `inc word [counter]`

Comment: thank you @Jester for the quick answer, and thank you for the link to the manual. That manual is quite hard for me to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NASM (unlike MASM) a bare symbol is an immediate value. For a memory reference enclose it in square brackets and indicate the required size.

```
 inc word [counter]
```

Comment: i did run into another problem though, i am compiling using macho64 and it complains about me using 32 bit addresses for memory, but i'll try to solve it by myself. Thank you for the very quick answer.

Comment: In 64 bit code use `default rel` at the top of the file or change to `inc word [rel counter]`.

Comment: as soon as i add `default rel` at the top, the program compiles but when run it crashes directly with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100001025)`